# data reader is reading the roll numbers twice as I open it second time & thrice as I open it third time

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

***[Dear Coders!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD14B.jpg)***

Hope u all are fine there.I am working on a school's Software.There are two buttons on Main Screen;Student Info List & Update Student Info.On Clicking Update Student Info , it opens the screen where you can edit the Student's Infromation.When I click on the combo box to select the Roll No.It shows all good.But when I go back to Main Screen & Click on Student Info List;It opens the data grid view(containing all information of the students).And then again I open to Update the Information,It shows the Roll No twice.As repeated the steps,it shows the roll no increasing.
Pictures are given in the form of link.

**Code is given below.Any help will be appriciated.**
*Thank you*

```
[try
        {
            int i = 0;
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Form1.connectionString))
            {
                string commandString = "SELECT RollNO  FROM Student1";
                // MessageBox.Show(commandString);
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    i = 1;
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(dr\[0\]);

                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually each time you are filling your combobox you are not clearing previous items call I have modified your code try this one

```
try
        {
            int i = 0;
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Form1.connectionString))
            {
                string commandString = "SELECT RollNO  FROM Student1";
                comboBox3.Items.Clear(); //first clear previous items then refill
                // MessageBox.Show(commandString);
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    i = 1;
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(dr[0]);
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```